# Share video and sticker Image to Instagram Story on Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, instagram, instagram-api

**How can I share a video as a background and an image as a sticker together to Instagram Story?**

This documentation has only one solution if both contents are images.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

I would like to send a background video together with a sticker image. Is that possible with Instagram Story?

**I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work:**

```
   // Define image asset URI and attribution link URL
    Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(backgroundPath));
    Uri stickerAssetUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(stickerPath));

    // Instantiate implicit intent with ADD_TO_STORY action,
    // background asset, and attribution link
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
    intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, "*/*");
    intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerAssetUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    callbackManager.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"), NatShareCallbacks.ACTIVITY_SHARE_INSTAGRAM_STORY);
```

But the example with two images works without problems. I see the problem mainly with **SetType**, because they are two different content types.

[EDIT]

Video alone without stickers had already worked for me on Android and the example of the documentation with image-background and image-sticker also works perfectly. But not video and sticker together.

It works under iOS without any problems:

```
NSData *backgroundVideo = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];

UIImage *appIcon = [UIImage imageNamed: [[[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIcons"] objectForKey:@"CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"]  objectAtIndex:0]];

// Verify app can open custom URL scheme, open
NSURL *urlScheme = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram-stories://share"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlScheme]) {
    // Assign background image asset and attribution link URL to pasteboard
    //NSArray *pasteboardItems = @[@{@"com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundVideo" : backgroundVideo}];
    NSArray *pasteboardItems = @[@{@"com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundVideo" : backgroundVideo, @"com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage" : UIImagePNGRepresentation(appIcon)}];
    NSDictionary *pasteboardOptions = @{UIPasteboardOptionExpirationDate : [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 5]};
    // This call is iOS 10+, can use 'setItems' depending on what versions you support
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setItems:pasteboardItems options:pasteboardOptions]; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlScheme options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
} else {
    // Handle older app versions or app not installed case

}
```

Comment: show me your video file name

Comment: have you try with image/* as type

Comment: @RutvikBhatt Video alone without stickers had already worked for me. so it shouldn't be the video path.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani I get an exception with "image/*"

- 12-12 12:22:19.551  2559 2830 E AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: IgExecutor #12
- 12-12 12:22:19.551  2559 2830 E AndroidRuntime  Process: com.instagram.android, PID: 2559
- 12-12 12:22:19.551  2559 2830 E AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug.

Facebook wrote:
"They've added the functionality now to Android as well, so you should be able to send a background with a sticker now."

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious things to check right away are:

1. Does your asset match these criteria:

   > Uri to an image asset (JPG, PNG) or video asset (H.264, H.265, WebM).
   >   Minimum dimensions 720x1280. Recommended image ratios 9:16 or 9:18.
   >   Videos can be 1080p and up to 20 seconds in duration. The Uri needs to
   >   be a content Uri to a local file on the device.
2. `intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, "*/*");` - the docs say that the second value of the function could be null, however I do not think that "*/*" is a valid mime-type: try with **MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO** - [Link to Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.FileColumns#MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) `intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);`

> MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO added in API level 11
>
> public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
>
> Constant for the MEDIA_TYPE column indicating that file is a video
>   file.
>
> Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

3. And finally - have you tested starting the activity as in the example:

```
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    activity.grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", stickerAssetUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Video alone without stickers had already worked for me. I probably should have written in addition. I'll try the rest tomorrow, thank you very much.

Comment: intent.setDataAndType expects a string as second parameter. But MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO is an int.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same approach as on Facebook's official documentation then tested on `Huawai P9 Lite` (N),  `Huawai P20 Lite` (O) and `Samsung S8` (O) - it only worked on `Samsung S8` for still not known reasons. I gave up trying since, obviously, it's not working on most of the phones.

The most interesting thing is that sharing on the **feed** with same method worked just fine:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_FEED"); //feed
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(image, "image/jpeg");

Uri image = getImageUri();

Activity activity = getActivity();
if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```