# Share Image with text(hashtags) as instagram story in android

Tags: android, instagram, share-intent

I would like to share an image with few hashtags as text with them (#foodLOve, #RestaurantName etc) as my Instagram story in android. I have no issues with the image but the text I'm including is not appearing. I'm not using Facebook SDK here. Here is my code:

```
Uri imageUri = getImageUri(context,((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
       // String shareText = "Hey, check this out ! I'm watching :  \n ";


        String shareText = "#FoodLove"+"#RestaurantName";
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
        intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("content_url", shareText);
        //intent.setType("image/text");
        activity.grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", imageUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        /*intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);*/
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //
        // intent.setClassName("com.instagram.android","com.instagram.share.handleractivity.StoryShareHandlerActivity");

        try {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Please install Instagram to share this content ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Referring to this link also didn't help much : 
[Share video and sticker Image to Instagram Story on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596982/share-video-and-sticker-image-to-instagram-story-on-android)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram no more supports the `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` to share image or video with captions for better quality. So, you can not share your caption with image or video. Even official documentation does not provide any field for text.

[Instagram doc for Android Intent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/)

What you can do is instead of calling

`Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");`

Replace with the

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Or you can follow the same example which is in the official documentation for sharing on Instagram.

Comment: if I replace my intent to Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); it will give all the possible apps which can share image type, which is the very thing I'm trying to avoid. I specifically want to share this as "Instagram story only".  If you look at the code carefully Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is in the comments. Please read te question and the code carefully. Thanks for trying.