# What is the proper way to send a video background asset and an image sticker layer to instagram in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, instagram

I want to share a video to instagram from my app, using my app logo as a sticker. [I have been following this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/?locale=en_US), but the results is that everytime I try to share, instagram opens, shows me my video and the sticker, it freezes for about a second, and then the sticker dissapears, only leaving me with my video and no sticker to be seen, even after posting said video.

[I have also read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596982/share-video-and-sticker-image-to-instagram-story-on-android), where they stated that not being able to share a sticker with a video was a bug with android, but it should now be fixed. The image Im using for the sticker is 640x480 which is the recommended size according to documentation so I dont think is the image size either. I can only think Im sharing it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
        Uri stickerAssetUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + R.class.getPackage().getName() + "/drawable/" + R.drawable.app_logo_sticker);
        File media = new File(localFilePath);
        Uri backgroundAssetUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), getString(R.string.file_provider), media);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, "video/mp4");
        intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerAssetUri);

        getActivity().grantUriPermission(
                "com.instagram.android", stickerAssetUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (getActivity().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the video file I was using for testing. The max duration for a background asset is 20 seconds, and while the file I was using was 20 seconds according the videoview, retrieving the actual duration of the video gave me 20333 milis which is over the limit specified in the documentation. I used a different file that actually meets the criteria and it works.